# Rails: Functionals Test fails for undefined method in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, view

I'm new of Rails and I have a problem with a functional test that fails for undefined method in view :

```
1) Error:
test_should_get_index(OrdersControllerTest):
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
app/views/orders/index.html.erb:19:in `_app_views_orders_index_html_erb__2011622583_2177866460_0'
app/views/orders/index.html.erb:14:in `_app_views_orders_index_html_erb__2011622583_2177866460_0'
app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:8:in `index'
/test/functional/orders_controller_test.rb:9:in `test_should_get_index'
```

It is all ok in the browser, only the test fails.

Here is the `views/orders/index.html.erb` file content:

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
<tr>
 <td><%= order.name %></td>
 <td><%= order.address %></td>
 <td><%= order.email %></td>
 <td><%= order.pay_type.name %></td>
```

`Pay_type` is another table that contains the pay type name; in orders table there is a foreign key called `pay_type_id`. In the browser I see correctly the pay type name with `order.pay_type.name` statement, but functional test fails.

`test_should_get_index:`

```
 test "should get index" do
   get :index
   assert_response :success
   assert_not_nil assigns(:orders)
 end
```

*orders fixtures:*

```
one:
  name: Dave Thomas
  address: MyText
  email: dave@example.org
  pay_type_id: 1

two:
  name: MyString
  address: MyText
  email: MyString
  pay_type_id: 1
```

*paytypes fixtures:*

```
one:
  id: 1
  name: Check

two:
  id: 2
  name: Credit Card

three:
  id: 3
  name: Purchase Order
```

*orders_controller:*

```
def index
@orders = Order.paginate :page=>params[:page], :order=>'created_at desc',
  :per_page => 10

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @orders }
end
end
```

Can somebody help me ?

I added `raise Exception.new(@orders.inspect)` in the view and i get following error:

```
`1) Error:
test_should_get_index(OrdersControllerTest):
ActionView::Template::Error: [#<Order id: 298486374, name: "MyString", address: "MyText", email: "MyString", created_at: "2013-02-12 14:05:11", updated_at: "2013-02-12 14:05:11", pay_type_id: 1>, #<Order id: 980190962, name: "Dave Thomas", address: "MyText", email: "dave@example.org", created_at: "2013-02-12 14:05:11", updated_at: "2013-02-12 14:05:11", pay_type_id: 1>]
app/views/orders/index.html.erb:14:in `_app_views_orders_index_html_erb__1955286768_2214618420_0'
app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:8:in `index'
/test/functional/orders_controller_test.rb:9:in `test_should_get_index'`
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you set `@orders` in your controller? Can you also try raising an exception in your view with `raise Exception.new(@orders.inspect)`

Comment: @Max I update my question with orders_controller code. Where do i put `raise Exception.new(@orders.inspect)` in my view ? Sorry, but i'm new of rails. Thanks so much .

Comment: Put it just before `<% @orders.each do |order| %>`. This will allow you to see exactly what `@orders` looks like in your test. Please add the line, run the tests, and then post the output.

Comment: @Max I update my question, because the error code was too long.

Comment: @Max It's incredible. I only commented the `raise Exception.new(@orders.inspect)` statement , and now all works perfectly. i can't explain myself this strange thing. thanks so much at all

Answer (score 0):

You have something in @orders that is nil, and when you call `name` on it it gives that error. Make sure that @orders only contains orders, and doesn't contain nil when you are testing.